# Carrying out of loop so as to do the following operation

Tags: arrays, matlab, loops

consider an area with size m*n. Here the size of m and n is unknown. Now I am extracting data from each point in the area. I am scanning the area first going in the x direction till m point and the again returning to m=0 and n=1, i.e the second row. Again I scan along the x direction till the end of m. An example of the data has been shown below. Here I get value for different x,y coordinates during the scan. I can carry out operation between the first two points in x direction by

```
p1 = A{1}; %%reading the data from the text file
p2 = A{2};
LA=[p1 p2];

for m=1:length(y)
p= LA(m,1);
t= LA(m,2);

%%and 

q=LA(m+1,1)
r=LA(m+1,2)
```

I want to do the same for y axis. That is I want to operate between first point in x=0 and y=1 then between x=2 and y=1 and so on. Hope you have got it.

```
g x y
2 0 0
3 1 0
2 2 0
4 3 0
1 4 0
2 m 0
3 0 1
2 1 1
4 2 1
5 3 1
.
.
.
.
2 m 1
```

now I was thinking of a logic where I will first find the size of n by counting the number of zeros

```
NUMX = 0;
while y((NUMX+1),:) == 0
    NUMX = NUMX + 1;
    end
NU= NUMX;
```

And then I was thinking of applying the following loop

```
 for m=1:NU:n-1
 %%and
   p= LA(m,1);
   t= LA(m,2);


%%and 

q=LA(m+1,1)
r=LA(m+1,2)
```

But its showing error. Please help!!

```
??? Attempted to access del2(99794,:); index out of bounds because
size(del2)=[99793,1].
```

Here NUMX=198

Comment: post a working example and the error message

Comment: Do you realize, that `NUMX=198` does not match `size(del2)=[99793,1]`, because `198` is not an even divisor of `99793`?

Answer (score 0):

*Comment: The nomenclature in your question is inconsistent, making it difficult to understand what you are doing. The variable `del2` you mention in the error message is nowhere to be seen.*

1.) Let's start off by creating a minimal working example that illustrates the data structure and provides knowledge of the dimensions we want to retrieve later. You matrix is not `m x n` but `m*n x 3`.
The following example will set up a matrix with data similar to what you have shown in your question:

```
M = zeros(8,3);

for J=1:4
    for I=1:2
        M((J-1)*2+I,1) = rand(1);
        M((J-1)*2+I,2) = I;
        M((J-1)*2+I,3) = J-1;
    end
end

M = 
    0.469    1    0
    0.012    2    0
    0.337    1    1
    0.162    2    1
    0.794    1    2
    0.311    2    2
    0.529    1    3
    0.166    2    3
```

2.) Next, let's determine the number of `x` and `y`, to use the nomenclature of your question:

```
NUMX = 0;
while M(NUMX+1,3) == 0
    NUMX = NUMX + 1;
end

NUMY = size(M,1)/NUMX;

NUMX = 
      2

NUMY = 
      4
```

3.) The data processing you want to do still is unclear, but here are two approaches that can be used for different means:
(a)

```
COUNT = 1;
for K=1:NUMX:size(M,1)
    A(COUNT,1) = M(K,1);
    COUNT = COUNT + 1;
end
```

In this case, you step through the first column of `M` with a step-size corresponding to `NUMX`. This will result in all the values for `x=1`:

```
A =
   0.469
   0.337
   0.794
   0.529
```

(b) You can also use `NUMX` and `NUMY` to reorder `M`:

```
for J=1:NUMY
    for I=1:NUMX
        NEW_M(I,J) = M((J-1)*NUMX+I,1);
    end
end

NEW_M =
       0.469    0.337    0.794    0.529
       0.012    0.162    0.311    0.166
```

The matrix `NEW_M` now is of size `m x n`, with the values of constant `y` in the columns and the values of constant `x` in the rows.

Concluding remark: It is unclear how you define `m` and `n` in your code, so your specific error message cannot be resolved here.

Comment: @rohan : Please consider accepting this answer by clicking the checkmark (✓) next to the voting buttons or comment on what doesn't work for you.